# Jquery dblclick doesn't respond to same cursor position

Tags: jquery, css, clone

I have a function that clones an img when doubleclicked. However, if i click in the exact same spot on the original img, a clone is not produced beyond the first. I have to move the cursor some small distance, even 1px.

This issue crops up in several jquery effects i have going on, that involve dlbclick or hover.

Comment: can you post your jquery code? (+html if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="home"></div>
<img src="images/media_library.png" width="115" height="27" alt="df" id="clo"/>

$('#clo').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).clone(true).appendTo('#home');
});
```